# Hide/Show table in my Email with the use of a button

Tags: html, css, email

Recently I was setting up the code for sending my email and styling it with html/css. Though one person thought the mail text was quite messy and had the idea to create a button that shows or hides a table (so a show more or show less button).

This wouldn't be to much of a problem in a normal web page since its allowed to use either javascript, jquery or plain coding in there, however this is not allowed in mails (most mail clients don't support it).

So the question is, is it possible to give a button functionality in my email so that it shows or hides a particular table in my email body? And if so, how?

Here is some code I have so far for my email:

```
sBody="<font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""black"">Dear " & FirstName & ",<br><br>"
                sBody=sBody & "Recently you made a ticket concerning '<b>" & FormSubject &  "</b>'.<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "We will try to answer your question as quick as possible." & "<br><br>"

            sBody=sBody &  "<br>"

            sBody=sBody & "<table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0""><tr>" 
            sBody=sBody & "<td align=""center"" width=""200"" height=""35"" bgcolor=""#000091"" style=""-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;"">"
            sBody=sBody & "<a href=""http://www.EXAMPLE.com/"" style=""font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block""><span style=""color: #FFFFFF"">Show ticket information</span></a>"
            sBody=sBody & "</td></tr> </table>"

            sBody=sBody &  "<table id=""tickethide"" style=""display: none;"">"
            sBody=sBody &  "<tr><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Send date</th><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">For department</th><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Type of ticket</th><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Subject</th><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Ticket description</th></tr>"

            sBody=sBody &  "<tr bgcolor=""#BEC0F7"">"
```

I didn't pasted all of the body in here since it would give an overflow of code that isn't useful for this problem. Also notice I am programming (and setting up this email) in a classic ASP file, so that is the reason why I am using the & and double "". The created button now also uses a href but this will be left out once it has the show/hide functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure this can be done in a failsafe way. My method involves fairly modern CSS, so I don't know which email clients it works in. It works in SeaMonkey, but I don't have MS Office to test with.

The trick is to use a checkbox, that, when checked, makes the following block visible using a CSS "sibling" selector. No Javascript needed.

```
<style>
#showtable + label {color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer}
#showtable, #table {display:none}
#showtable:checked ~ #table {display:block;}
</style>

<font face="Verdana, Arial" size=2 color="black">Dear [[FirstName]] ,<br><br>
Recently you made a ticket concerning '<b> [[FormSubject]] </b>'.<br>
We will try to answer your question as quick as possible. <br><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="showtable" />
<label for="showtable">Click to show or hide the table</label>

<br><br>
<font id="table" color="#99FFDD" size=3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#006633">
<tr><td>This is the table</td></tr>
<tr><td>with the information</td></tr>
</table>
</font>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/f8h6ns9j/) where you can test live, but of course that's a normal webpage. For a real test, send the HTML to yourself in an email. Make sure to include the `<style>` block.